# R - Unable to change entry in a list of lists - Error: could not find function "(<-"

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists, and when I try to modify one entry I get an error. As an example here is a dummy code that produces the error:

```
    list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
    list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
    mylist <- list(list1, list2)

    (mylist[[1]])[[1]] <- 555
```

I can avoid this by creating a temp list from the list of lists. However, it is annoying if I have to deal with this a lot. Any ideas for one line of code that solves the issue?

Comment: As nate hinted, the parens around variables are not always a "no-op". For instance, typically `a <- 1` does its work *invisibly*, whereas `(a <- 1)` is not, because the parens force it similar to how `(9)` just prints to the console. However, you cannot then assign something into this parenthesized expression. I often use my first example in SO answers to tersely assign and show, but it is (IMHO) never needed/useful in any production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(mylist[[1]])` and `mylist[[1]]` have the same value when evaluated

but when you do :

```
mylist[[1]] <- 1
```

The parser calls the function `[[<-` and executes :

```
`[[<-`(mylist,1,value=1)
```

Whereas when you do :

```
(mylist[[1]]) <- 1
```

The parser calls the function `(<-` which is not defined (you'd have the same error with `(x) <- 1`).

`(mylist[[1]])[[1]] <- 1` also calls `(<-` though it call `[[<-` first.

I don't know exactly how the parser works but if you redefine :

```
`[[<-` <- function(a,b,value) {print("hello");base::`[[<-`(a,b,value)}
```

you will see it prints before giving an error.

```
(mylist[[1]])[[1]] <- 1
[1] "hello"
Error in (mylist[[1]])[[1]] <- 1 : could not find function "(<-"
```

Make sure to clean this up:

```
rm(`[[<-`)
```

This would make your code work, though you should really just drop the parentheses:

```
`(<-` <- function(x,value) `<-`(x,value)
(mylist[[1]])[[1]] <- 555 #works
```

Answer (score 3):

Why the brackets? Just do `mylist[[1]][[1]] <- 555`

This corresponds to

```
list1 <- list(a = 555, b = 3)
list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```